# Swift UIView Animate doesn't work properly

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

Slide up animation will be triggered when a button is clicked.

```
    func animation_onClick(action: String) {
          let up = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -30)

          myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)

          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
              self.myView.transform = up            
          }, completion: nil)
    }
```

My code means when the function runs, `myView`’s position will be set to (0, 0) referring to its original position every time before it was set to (0, -30).

But when I run the app, I repeatedly click the button, somehow `myView` doesn't go back to its origin, it goes below where it should be. What I mean is it's not supposed to go below its origin.

See the gif below.

[image]

Comment: try to disable button or ignore animation func until animation block completed

Comment: This is done intentionally because I’m building the app for android too using kotlin, but I don’t see this problem @AlexandrKolesnik

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
func animation_onClick(action: String) {
    myView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    myView.transform = .identity

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -30)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```